# Rational values of $f(x) = \left(1 + \frac {1}{x}\right)^x$ and $g (x) = \left(1 + \frac {1}{x}\right)^{x+1}$

Tags: number-theory

It seems to me that the functions $f(x) = \left(1 + \frac {1}{x}\right)^x$ and $g (x) = \left(1 + \frac {1}{x}\right)^{x+1}$, defined for every positive real $x$, assume simultaneously rational values if, and only if, $x$ is integer.
I tested by assigning values to $x$, but I could not elaborate proof of this statement.

Suppose that f (x) and g (x) are rational. Let A, B, C and D be positive integers, with gcd (A, B) = gcd (C, D) = 1. Let f (x) = A / B and g (x) = C / D.

So:

C / D = (A / B) (1 + 1 / x) and, therefore, after the calculations:

x = (BC-AD) / AD

Well, now I would like to conclude that x is integer, but I do not know if it is possible.

I need help.

Comment: That can't be true.  $f(1)=2,f(2)=2.15166$ and the function is continuous so it hits every rational number between.

Comment: @lulu Oh.  Well darn, I'm stupid for trying...

Comment: This becomes much more interesting if you restrict the domain of the function to rational numbers!

Comment: @SimpleArt  Well, maybe $f(x)\in \mathbb Q$ for $x\notin \mathbb Z$ implies that $x$ is irrational?

Comment: @lulu Yes, that was just about where I was getting in the not-yet-existent answer I am trying to write up :-D

Comment: @lulu Stronger, I think it implies $x$ is transcendental by that one theorem about algebraic numbers raised to each other.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfond%E2%80%93Schneider_theorem

Comment: @SimpleArt  I don't immediately see how that applies.  Theres plenty of cases where $a,b,a^b$ are all rational.

Comment: f(1) =  2,    f(2) = 9/4

Comment: @lulu I meant that when $x$ is irrational, it must be transcendental, right?  If $x$ were non-rational algebraic and $f(x)$ were rational, it would contradict the theorem.

Comment: @PauloArgolo  You are correct, I was giving $f(1.5)$ not $f(2)$.  But it doesn't really matter what the values are...the point is that it must hit all the rationals between the two points.  For example, we see that there is some $x_0$ with $1<x_0<1.5$ and $f(x_0)=2.1$ and clearly $x_0\notin \mathbb Z$.

Comment: @SimpleArt Ah, that sounds right.

Comment: @PauloArgolo  Wait...were you saying that $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ simultaneously rational should imply that $x\in \mathbb Z$?  I thought you were asking two separate questions.  of course if both of these values are rational then the quotient $\frac {g(x)}{f(x)}=(1+\frac 1x)$ is rational which at least implies that $x$ is rational.

Comment: @PauloArgolo  With the simultaneous condition you are now asking the same question we've been asking in the comments.  Namely, if $x,f(x),g(x)$ are simultaneously rational does that imply that $x$ is an integer?

Answer (score 2):

If $x\in\mathbb N$, then

$$f(x)=\frac{(x+1)^x}{x^x}$$

which is trivially rational.

Assume that $x$ is a non-integer rational number of the form $a/b$, where $a,b\in\mathbb N$ and it is in reduced form.  Then, if we are to have $f(x)$ be rational,

$$f(a/b)=\left(\frac{a+b}a\right)^{a/b}=\frac cd$$

$$\implies\begin{cases}(a+b)^a=c^b\\a^a=d^b\end{cases}$$

From here, we can see that $d$ must factor into $a$, but this only occurs if $b$ has a common factor with $a$ so that the amount of factors on both sides is the same.  Then we have contradiction, since $x$ must be in reduced form, which implies $a$ does not divide $b$.

By the [Gelfond-Schneider theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfond%E2%80%93Schneider_theorem), if $x$ is algebraic and not rational, then $f(x)$ is transcendental, which is definitely not what we want.

Thus, the only solutions are if $x$ is a natural number or if $x$ is transcendental.  An argument of continuity will show the existence of these transcendental cases.

Comment: I had to edit the question.

Comment: I kept writing this down, but never convinced myself. Where, for example, do you use the fact that $b\neq 1$?

Comment: @lulu That $x$ is non-integer rational.  First line.

Comment: @PauloArgolo Well, that changes it drastically.  If lulu wants to answer that one, go ahead :D

Comment: Oddly, the simultaneous question turns out to be equivalent to the one we posed each other.  Note that $\frac {g(x)}{f(x)}=(1+\frac 1x) $ so if they are both rational then so is $x$.

Comment: I see where you assumed $x$ was non-integral but I don't see where you used it.  If I take $x=2$, where does your argument break down?  I mean...you have $d^b=a^a$.  How does that imply that $b$ divides $a$?  $2^8=4^4$ but $8$ does not divide $4$.

Comment: @lulu I did not cover the cases for $x\in\mathbb N$, as I considered them trivial.  Think I should add?

Comment: The integer case is trivial...But I'm just not following your logic.  Like I say, it is not true that $d^b=a^a\implies b\,|\,a$ as the example $2^8=4^4$ shows.

Comment: @lulu Oh, my bad.  I meant that $a$ and $b$ had common factors :-)

Comment: Ok.  if $p$ is a prime dividing $b$ then it is certainly true that what you have shows that $p\,|\,a$ .  I'm convinced.  Thanks!

Comment: @lulu And thanks for clearing things up!  :D  I'm actually horrible at this stuff IMO, its not my "tag" of expertise.

Comment: Alas, the argument still needs some work.  I was wrong...it isn't true that $d^b=a^a$ means that $a,b$ have to have factors in common.  Take $a=2^3$, so $a^a=2^{3a}=2^{24}$. Then we could have $d=2^8,b=3$. I keep making versions of the same error on this problem...I'll think about it later in the day.